# performSegueWithIdentifier called from dismissViewControllerAnimated's completion block leads to black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to understand a really annoying bug. I apologize in advance: it is probably hard to reproduce. I am just hoping someone stumbled upon a similar situation before and can shed some light.

In my `Storyboard`, I have two `UIViewController` `A` and `B`. I defined two segues from `A` to `B`, each with a different identifier (based on the identifier, I setup `B` differently).

- the segues are triggered programatically from `A` with
  `performSegueWithIdentifier`
- the segues use custom transitions
- they are dismissed from `A` with

.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{        
            completionBlock();
}];
```

If I trigger the first segue, then in its `dismissViewControllerAnimated`'s `completionBlock` trigger the other one, I get a black screen when I dismiss the second segue. As if something was wrong with the views stack. On the other side, if I trigger the first segue, then later (outside of the completion block) I trigger the second one, everything is just fine. In addition, if I replace my custom transitions with standard modal ones everything works just fine (but I checked and rechecked my custom transition code and it looks right).

So somehow, when you `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, it looks like things are not quite "ready" in the completion block.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: what is your completion block code

Comment: @iDev I reduced it for testing purpose to just `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

The `dismissViewControllerAnimated` completion block is firing somewhere around the same time as `viewWillAppear`.  You will get similar, if not identical, results if you try to call `performSegueWithIdentifer` directly in any `viewWillAppear` method.  The earliest a segue should be performed is as the first line of execution in `viewDidAppear`.  The completion block fires before `viewDidAppear` (put `NSLog` statements everywhere to verify the order).

Comment: Thanks. I did not know. That being said, I am not sure how it helps here: A's view is already shown anyway when I call the first `performSegueWithIdentifer`. So `viewDidAppear` will never be called again after I dismiss the first B. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is called once on A before it moves to B, then as you navigate from B back to A, A goes through `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  B's completion block is trying to perform a segue before A is in it's `viewDidAppear` on the second appearance of the view.  This is causing the problem.

Comment: For some clarity, add NSLog statements in all the life cycle events to watch the order.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me on this. But it looks like there is a problem when you use a custom transition. When you navigate from B back to A, A does NOT go through `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. I thought the problem was with my custom transition code, but it does not look like so. I tried on this code http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3871-golden-opportunity-custom-transitions/ and the same happens. `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are not called when the modal view is dismissed.